# .net core custom authorization with attribute best practice

Tags: c#, .net-core

In the Microsoft Docs about net core authorization there are the following article and code example of how to make a custom attribute "MinimumAgeAuthorizeAttribute".
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0

The code makes it possible to use the attribute like this:

```
[MinimumAgeAuthorize(10)]
public IActionResult RequiresMinimumAge10()
```

I came up with this idea instead using only one attribute that do not need any other classes or registrations of handlers etc.

```
internal class MinimumAgeAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private int Age { get; }

        public MinimumAgeAuthorizeAttribute(int age) => Age = age;

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var logger = (ILogger<MinimumAgeAuthorizeAttribute>)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ILogger<MinimumAgeAuthorizeAttribute>));

            // Log as a warning so that it's very clear in sample output which authorization policies 
            // (and requirements/handlers) are in use
            logger.LogWarning("Evaluating authorization requirement for age >= {age}", Age);

            // Check the user's age
            var dateOfBirthClaim = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth);
            if (dateOfBirthClaim != null)
            {
                // If the user has a date of birth claim, check their age
                var dateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(dateOfBirthClaim.Value);
                var age = DateTime.Now.Year - dateOfBirth.Year;
                if (dateOfBirth > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-age))
                {
                    // Adjust age if the user hasn't had a birthday yet this year
                    age--;
                }

                // If the user meets the age criterion, mark the authorization requirement succeeded
                if (age >= Age)
                {
                    logger.LogInformation("Minimum age authorization requirement {age} satisfied", Age);
                    return;
                }

                logger.LogInformation("Current user's DateOfBirth claim ({dateOfBirth}) does not satisfy the minimum age authorization requirement {age}",
                    dateOfBirthClaim.Value,
                    Age);
            }
            else
            {
                logger.LogInformation("No DateOfBirth claim present");
            }

            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }
```

I find this solution more straightforward and less complex. But...
Are there any security issues with my solution?
Are there any other benefits by using the solution described in microsoft docs instead of my solution?

Additional fact:
In my case the api uses jwt token authorization.

Comment: You can inject your `ILogger` via a constructor, instead of having to go through the `HttpContext` to get it

Comment: @Jonesopolis I do not think I can do that here actually. Since the constructor is used when adding the attribute to the method.

Comment: Working with the existing policy system makes it easier to add and remove requirements as needed. I would personally avoid mixing and matching because it may be confusing to figure out what current methods there are to authorize. However at the end of the day it's just logic packaged differently, so there's nothing wrong with this. The downside of handlers/requirements is a lot of files but the upside is flexibility.